# Geographic distance between two regions

Tags: geolocation, distance, geospatial, geo

I am currently trying to calculate the geographic distance between two regions as I want to correlate it with their similarity of another aspect (e.g., similarity in word usage).

Currently, I have used a simple approach of determining the geographic center point of each region (a region corresponds to a province/state of a country) and then calculate the Haversine distance [1] between these two points.

This approach seems rather ad-hoc to me and as I am no expert in this area, I am curious if you guys know a more reasonable approach.

Thanks!

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: What programming language did you implement your "simple approach" with? Also, this is quite a conceptual question whereas SO is better at helping you with tangible programming problems.

Comment: A suggestion. If you are looking at US and Canada you can get population centroids from the census data. It may be more interesting relationship in looking at the distance between centers of population between states/provinces.

Comment: @MathiasMüller This is done in Java. Any ideas for a better place to ask this?

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode I only look at European regions. Concretely, only German speaking ones (Germany, Austria, Switzerland).

Comment: Alright. Now, in what way is your simple approach unsatisfying or how does it being "rather ad-hoc" influence the outcome?

Comment: You can try to reverse engineer a population centroid per state by finding a midpoint between the coordinates of all the major cities in the state. You could also weigh each point (city centroid) by population. Maxmind offers a free db of major cities and coordinates: http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

Comment: As an alternative, you could download the NGA GNS datasets for Germany, Austria and Switzerland. They will contain records for each 1st level administrative division (e.g., state) and an 'area centroid'

Comment: Do you mean this one: http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.htm? How is the area centroid calculated?

Answer (score 0):

In the area you are focusing on, there is very often only one major city by administrative division (Bundesland, Kanton, ...). Maybe a reasonable approach would be to take the coordinates of this major city. (e.g. Zürich city for Kanton Zürich, Stuttgart for Bade-Württemberg)

Another point in the favour of doing so is that most of the transport facilities and communication flows will go through this point.